# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test and Regression to derive the goodness of fit for negative binomial and Poisson distribution in R

Tags: r, regression, goodness-of-fit

I have a vector dataset dt and only a few of 500 observations is given below.

```
[1]  0  4  8 13 15  1  0  5  4  6  0  0  0  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  3  0 10 15  0 23  0  6  0 10  2 15  0  3  0  2  0
 [39]  3  0 42  4  6 12  3  2  0  0  0  2  3  9  6  0  3  2  1  6  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  1
```

I want to check if the distribution of data follows a negative binomial distribution or Poisson distribution better using the KS test and regression. There are only a few R packages available for the KS test of which not all give a good summary and some are no longer valid.

What I have tried?

**Package iZID**

```
install.packages("iZID")
library("iZID")
dis.kstest(dt,nsim=100,bootstrap=TRUE,distri='nb')$pvalue
dis.kstest(dt,nsim=100,bootstrap=TRUE,distri='Poisson')$pvalue
```

Returns

```
> dis.kstest(dt,nsim=100,bootstrap=TRUE,distri='nb')$pvalue
[1] 0
> dis.kstest(dt,nsim=100,bootstrap=TRUE,distri='Poisson')$pvalue
[1] 0
```

**Question**
First, With the above results it’s hard to recommend which distribution is a better fit.  Second, I have also used `ks.test()` in `dgof` package but it needs initialization of `lambda` value for Poisson which is unknown and also Negative binomial should have a `probability` value initialized which is unknown. Third, I receive an error suggesting that `goodfit()` in `vcd` package is not available hence couldn't use this tool.

1. Can I use a ks-test package other than `dgof`, `iZID`, and `vcd`?
2. Can I use regression to compare the AIC of two distributions using `glm` in R? In that case, how to build the model? What is X and Y?

---

## Data in `dput` format

```
dt <-
c(0L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 10L, 15L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 
10L, 2L, 15L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 42L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
```

Comment: ks should be used with continuous data. In your case you have discrete data, why not directly apply the goodness of fit test?

Comment: Could you suggest any package to do that?

Comment: use Base R there is the `chisq.test` function. Best practice is to learn first about goodness of test then solve the problem. This should help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/is-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-valid-with-discrete-distributions

Comment: Can you share the code? Couldn't find anything for negative binomial

Comment: `chisq.test` can be used to test all discrete distributions. Learn first what goodness of test is. The solution to the link provided will give you the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to answer your question about `KS` test packages, yes, you can try the `ks` package in R.

It provides the `ks.test()` function that you could use to perform a `KS test` on your dataset.

For example, to perform a KS test on your dataset using a Poisson distribution, you can use the following code (of course I am assuming that you already have installed the package, before running the below code):

```
install.packages("ks", dependencies = T)

library(ks)
ks.test(dt, "ppois", lambda=mean(dt))
```

Here,
"ppois" is the Poisson distribution,
"lambda" is an estimate for the `rate parameter of the Poisson distribution` and we have set it to the mean of your data

The above code returns:

```
Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  dt
D = 0.44349, p-value = 2.078e-13
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Which means:

> The p-value is very small (2.078e-13), thus, suggesting a strong evidence
> against the null hypothesis.
> Therefore, you can reject the null hypothesis that the data follow the specified theoretical distribution at the significance level of 0.05, and hence, conclude that the data do not follow the theoretical distribution.

Similarly, you could use the `qnbinom` distribution for the negative binomial distribution.

Now, to answer your second question about comparing the AIC of two distributions using regression, what you could use is `glm()` native function in R.

All you need to do is, first, create an output variable `Y` that represents the count data, and then an explanatory (input) variable `X` that refers to the index of each observation in your dataset.

Now you can fit two models; one, with the Poisson Distributions and, second, with the Negative Binomial Distributions, respectively, and compare their AIC values to determine which distribution provides a better fit.

```
library(ks)
library(MASS)

Y <- dt            # create response var

X <- 1:length(Y)   # create independent (input) var

modelPD <- glm(Y ~ X, family = "poisson")   # fit the Poisson Distribution

modelNBD <- glm.nb(Y ~ X) # fit the Negative Binomial Distribution from MASS packages

# compare two AICs
AIC(modelPD)
AIC(modelNBD)
```

Which returns:

```
688.5675 and 334.3564
```

And as we know, lower the AIC value, the better the model fits the data.
Therefore, we can conclude that the `Negative Binomial Distribution` provides a better fit to the data compared to the `Poisson Distribution`.

Let me know if this helps...